# Save response of mysql query to a variable for later use

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express

I'm currently writing a backend API for a private message system, and I've come across an issue writing one of my functions. I need to save the response of an asynchronous call to a variable for use outside of said asynchronous call.

I'll present the code before explaining further:

```
app.get("/api/users/:UserID/messages/deletemessage/:MessageID", function(req, res){

    var messageID = parseInt(req.params.MessageID);
    var message = null;  

    connection.query("SELECT * FROM Message WHERE MessageID = ?", messageID, function(err, resp){
        if(!err){
            message = resp[0];
        }
    });
    console.log(message);
    //continue using the message variable here to perform more functionality...
});
```

You can see I'm trying to assign the `message` variable to the response of the select query of the mysql database.

When the function runs, `null` is printed to the screen. I know why this happens, it's because the `console.log` statement is called before the query to the database is completed.

My question is, how do I fix this issue to use the message variable outside of the scope of the database query?

I've only tried this, which hasn't worked:

```
app.get("/api/users/:UserID/messages/deletemessage/:MessageID", function(req, res){

    var messageID = parseInt(req.params.MessageID);
    var message = null;  

    connection.query("SELECT * FROM Message WHERE MessageID = ?", messageID, function(err, resp){
        if(!err){
            connection.end(); //try to end the connection so hopefully it assigns
            message = resp[0];
        }
    });
    console.log(message);
    //continue using the message variable here to perform more functionality...
});
```

Comment: You don't "fix" it, you code around it, waiting for the result before you do anything else etc.

Comment: @adeneo is there an accepted or standard way of 'coding around it'? What if I needed to use the result right away? Is there a way of waiting?

Comment: Sure, you use the callbacks, or implement promises to wait for a result. How you solve the issue depends on how you're using the returned data, and the reason for having to *have to have it right away*.

Comment: Try to avoid ever using `select *`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Node.js you'd have to move the log statement into the query functions, where the `message` variable is assigned.

Node isn't gonna wait for that query to be done before logging. Node just pipes data from one place to another, it doesn't really wait or "lock" since its a async language.

So the way around it is to call one function within another, within another and another and you might think that this gets messy and it really does. It's called [callback hell](http://callbackhell.com/).

There are ways around out and many have become standards today. Callback functions get really messy and result in callback hell so just use [Promise Chains](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2015/09/28/chaining-promises-in-javascript.aspx) instead or [Yield expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/yield).

Yield expressions work in generator functions. They're basically regular functions with a `*` after the `function` like this:

```
function* () {
  // generator function
  // you can use the "yield" keyword here
}
```

Just bare in mind though that Node.js doesn't interpret generator functions by default. You have to use a module like [co](https://www.npmjs.com/package/co) which allows you to run them.

co is pretty simple to use. Just place a generator functions inside a co function and it'll work. Like this:

```
var co = require('co');

co(function* () {
  // you can yield here
});
```

So your code might look something like this:

```
var co = require('co');

app.get("/api/users/:UserID/messages/deletemessage/:MessageID", function(req, res){
    co(function* () {
        var messageID = parseInt(req.params.MessageID);

        var resp = yield connection.query("SELECT * FROM Message WHERE MessageID = ?", messageID);
        // NOTE THE YIELD ^

        var message = resp[0];
        console.log(message);
    });
});
```

A few things to bare in mind about yield expressions and generator functions:

- `co` is just a generator function interpreter for Node v4.x and below, Node v6.x interprets generator functions out of the box so you won't need it there.
- to use yield expressions with the database queries you're gonna have to replace your database module with one that supports `co` or promises like https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql-promise same goes for any other module, you can only yield their results if they support promises or `co`
- express.js requires you to use co to add generator support but there's another web framework called [Koa](https://www.npmjs.com/package/koa) which replaces the function in `app.get` with a generator function. So you can yield directly inside of the request function.